# image in black when loading it from server

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got weird behaviour in my app, an image is loaded from server in `UIView`:

```
[self.imageFrame addSubview:self.myImage];
```

myImage is an instance of a class that extends from `UIImageView` class. The first time the image gets loaded fine, but the second time, i got a black background, the third time is fine, the fourth is with black background, and so on.

I try to print the image description in the debugger, so the first time, when the image is correctly loaded, i got this description:

```
(EGOImageView *) $7 = 0x0c940e80 <CustomImageView: 0xc940e80; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (8 5; 72 72); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc940f80>>
```

The second time, when i got the black image background, the description i got is:

```
(EGOImageView *) $8 = 0x0c9bfec0 <EGOImageView: 0xc9bfec0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (8 5; 72 72); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1043dea0>>
```

The description is the same as you can see. But i don't know what may cause the problem. Any suggestion? Thanx in advance.

Comment: It is not the same - the first time it is an instance of CustomImageView, the second time it appears to be EGOImageView.

Comment: Typo, sorry, it's the EGOImageView library

Answer (score 0):

In your example output, your comment says that both log messages should be EGOImageView - just to make this clear - so both log messages are essentially the same.

The root problem is that when you get a black view, your code has not set the UIImageView subclass's image property.

My suggestion is that do a couple of things:

- set the background color of the UIImageView subclass to some defined color (ie, red, green, blue etc). If you have different "categories" of images, or ways you set images, then use a different color for each. This may give you more clues when you get a blank imageView.
- log the image property in your log message.

EDIT:

- when you load an image, make sure the frame of the imageview has the appropriate size (and at least some size) [I've solved several problems but setting the appropriate frame).

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, actually, i may mis explain my issue. The image is there and it's returned from the server correctly, `NSLog(@"%@",[myImageURL description]);`, i got always a valid URL, if i copy and paste that url on the browser, i can see the image correctly. The url of the image is valid on both cases, even when i got black thumbnail image. For the sake of curiosity, does this have any deal with the cache?

Comment: I don't know about the cache, but you say black image. did you set the background color of the imageView? If so then that image is in fact black (given that one has been set). iOS cannot render every image imaginable.